# Need to use chkdsk after every dismount of Seagate exfat drive in mac

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, mac, exfat

Do not start virtual machine program to use external disk without ejecting disk first from mac (better to always do it).

I get irritating problem and I can't find resolution to it. Can't I manually replace directory files to bring back ability to create files on this storage? Or it's only Windows 7 and Mac feature to prevent writing to dirty bit drive.

I have this problem on every version of Mac, but not with Windows 8-10 and I am not willing to wait every time it happens 3-4 hours for fixing to end.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This seems like a Windows 7 issue. My Macs with macOS Catalina and macOS Mojave are both fine when it comes to using disks formatted FAT, FAT32, exFAT, and NTFS for use between a Windows 8/10 and a Mac. Make sure that you are on the latest version on both your Mac and PC and that might help.

Comment: You could face this issue when there is improper shutdown of your computer or if your hard disk’s dirty bit is set. When a volume's dirty bit is set, autochk automatically checks the volume for errors the next time the computer is restarted. So you get chkdsk every time.